# object name dynamic create

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

i have a single question,

i have this JS.

```
Scene.platform = new MenuItem();
Scene.platform.init(...code...);
```

this works fine, but i have N platforms, how i creat dynamic?

i tryed :

```
for(i=0....){

Scene.platform+i = new MenuItem();  
or
Scene.platform.i = new MenuItem();

}
```

i need the result like that:

```
Scene.platform1 = new MenuItem();
Scene.platform2 = new MenuItem();
Scene.platform3 = new MenuItem();
```

its possible? thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like your `platformX` properties should really be an array.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic names you can use `[]` syntax.

```
Scene['platform' + i] = new MenuItem();
```

Example

```js
const Scene = {};

for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  Scene['platform' + i] = {};
}

console.log(Scene);
```

But think about to use array instead of object and push your items into that array. Then you can use indexes to get , for example, first item via [0], which in your object style can be named like `platform0`.

```js
const Scene = { platforms: [] };

for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  Scene.platforms.push({});
}

console.log(Scene.platforms[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an array:

```
Scene.platforms = [];
for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    Scene.platforms.push(new MenuItem());
}
```

Later, to access them, either loop through the array (see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476)) or index into it. E.g., if you want the first one:

```
Scene.platforms[0].doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you have variables like this:

```
platform1
platform2
platform...
platformN
```

What you really want is an **array**.  Give your object an array called `platforms`, then you can store your "platforms" in that array.  For example, if you have this:

```
Scene.platforms = [];
```

Then you can push elements to it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < someAmount; i++) {
    Scene.platforms.push(new MenuItem());
}
```